# Is there a simple way to prove pi is irrational using math, which is known understandable for someone doing HL Maths (Advance High School Maths)?

Tags: pi

In school I have learned from early on that pi is irrational, but is there a simply proof which I could understand to show that this is the case. I am doing HL Maths (IB, with discrete as the option topic), so ideally kept it at the high school level if possible. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know what "HL maths" is, but I'm guessing you know a bit of calculus: derivatives and integrals, right?

Comment: How is this one: https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bams/1183510788

Comment: The above is a proof by Ivan Niven. The first proof that $\pi$ is *transcendental* was given by Lindemann in 1882, and involved some quite complicated calculus. At least you should understand this. If not, read up what you don't understand, and see why the above proof is simply wonderful.

Comment: Wikipedia has a nice list of prooofs.